# Calling static function in different namespace inside Slim PHP REST handler

Tags: php, rest, http, namespaces, slim

I have a PHP REST application built with Slim (installed via `composer`), where a handler is not able to access a static method defined in a class in a different namespace.  The code looks like this:

```
namespace Main;

use Controller\MyController;

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/clients/:username', function($username) use($app) {
        echo "Test text";
        MyController::get($app, $username);
});
$app->run();
```

When I go to `application/clients/some_id`, I get the "Test text" output.  However, the `MyController::get` function is not entered.  From reading the logs, what's happening is the system is not being able to find the `MyController` class to call the `get` function.

What is the correct way to call the `get` function in `MyController` class?

Answer (score 1):

`use` expects a full class name so if your controller's namespace is Main\Controller you should say

```
use Main\Controller\MyController;
```

Your code is correct if MyController is in Controller namespace (on the same level as Main), in which case you probably have an autoloader problem.

Comment: Yep, `Controller` is a separate namespace at the same level of  the `Main` namespace.  What sort of problems could be related to the autoloader?  I'm using `composer`'s.  Thanks!